# Dropdown image not visible in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have made a dropdown in my site and added `background image` to it. I can see it fine in Firefox, but not able to see it using Chrome or IE.

Here is:
[my site](http://test.techkalph.com)

On the very top you can see a search icon. Upon hovering that you can see a pop out. Inside that I am using a dropdown.

You can see the images showing fine in Firefox but not using any other browser.

[image: Screenshot from Firefox:]

[image: Screenshot from chrome]:

Here is the select dropdown code I used:

**My JS**

```
function goToNewPage(dropdownlist){
    var url = dropdownlist.options[dropdownlist.selectedIndex].value;
    if (url != ""){
        window.open(url);
    }
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<form name="dropdown">
    <label>I am Looking for</label>
    <img src="http://test.techkalph.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Bee-searching1.png">
    <select accesskey="E" name="list">
        <option selected="">Please select one</option>
        <option style="background-image:url(http://test.techkalph.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/flowers271.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;" value="http://www.google.com/">Japanese Companies</option>
        <option style="background-image:url(http://test.techkalph.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/social16.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;" value="http://www.google.com/">Service Provider (Non-Japanese)</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.list)" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: not visible in firefox here

Comment: With firefox you can stylize options with some properties, but in another browsers you can't.

Comment: Works on Firefox - but I can't select any option. A better cross-browser solution would be to create your own drop-down list with images. You'll find many solutions for this if you google.

Comment: Styling a selects options is very inconsistent through browsers, I recommend to use a jQuery alternative e.g. [jQuery Selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in webkit (Google) browsers. You will need an alternative solution with `ul` and `li` elements.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Got your Problem. The code you are using only works with Firefox and Webkit browsers. You either have to use [JQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/) for yuor need, or you can also some code at [this](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/) link