# HTML select/option dropdown - background image doesn't appear in Chrome / Edge

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, select, html-select

I want image icons to appear as background image on the select/option element. It works perfectly on Firefox, but in Chrome the images don't appear at all?

Below is the sample code I use.

```
<select style="-webkit-appearance: none;">
  <option value="1" style="background:url('http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/anticlockwise-small-arrow-icons-57546.png') no-repeat right center">OPTION ONE</option>
  <option value="2" style="background:url('http://www.w3f.com/gifs/bullits/star3.gif') no-repeat right center">OPTION TWO</option>
</select>
```

I created this JS here: https://jsfiddle.net/03vaaL5o/

What should I do for the icons to appear correctly in Chrome and possibly all other modern browsers (Opera, Edge)?

Comment: Ok found a similar one here, but there is still no solution.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562473/dropdown-image-not-visible-in-chrome-and-ie

Answer (score 1):

As per the other article that you linked, this is not something that is consistent throughout browsers. Styling select boxes isn't officially supported. You should use something like this:

https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render