# Dropdown background image not rendering in IE

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have wanted to remove default background image of drop down. I have used "form control" and "dropdown" bootstrap class and replaced the background image. It is perfectly working in Chrome, Mozilla and Edge [ddl in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogjEl.png). But its not rendering properly in IE [ddl in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQvhU.png). Please help. I have attached both the images.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support background image on dropdown input fields. There's still an workaround. Look at the similar questions here on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/33562849/2160816