# asp.net dropdownlist image country flags

Tags: asp.net, dropdown

Please take a look at the screenshot where GB flag is showing as css test span and a dropdown list showing list of countries without flag images and I need to show flag images !

[image]

```
<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></span>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 pl0">
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control thintext" ID="lstCountryLivingIn" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
<asp:ListItem Text="Please Select..." Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
Dim li As New ListItem()
li.Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("CountryId").ToString
li.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("CountryTitle").ToString & " ( " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("CountryPhoneCode").ToString & " )"

‘ I need to add some css / style or attribute here to show country flags

lstCountryLivingIn.Items.Add(li)
Next
```

I need to use css / styling at code-behind to display country flags in each dropdown items but I'm not sure how???

I have 2 character ISO country codes such as “gb” in country table and I have all flags in svg format

Further reference:
http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/09/dropdownlist-item-with-custom-icon.html

Answer (score 0):

You can download them at [here](http://flag-icon-css.lip.is/). Based on the sample link you have mentioned, you can set the background image / css for each combo items.

EDIT: We cannot achieve this with pain dropdown, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562473/dropdown-image-not-visible-in-chrome-and-ie) question. If we use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns) or [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render) dropdowns we can achieve the same.